# correct way to increase hdfs java heap memory

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I'm getting the following errors in my hadoop namenode log:

```
2015-12-20 06:15:40,717 WARN  [IPC Server handler 21 on 9000] ipc.Server
(Server.java:run(2029)) - IPC Server handler 21 on 9000, call
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.DatanodeProtocol.blockReport 
from 172.31.21.110:46999 Call#163559 Retry#0: 
error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2015-12-20 06:15:42,710 WARN  [IPC Server handler 22 on 9000] ipc.Server
(Server.java:run(2029)) - IPC Server handler 22 on 9000, call 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.DatanodeProtocol.blockReport from 
172.31.24.250:45624 Call#164898 Retry#0: 
error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

which results in all the nodes being listed as dead.

I have checked other stackoverflow questions and the most useful suggestion seems to be that I need to set the `mapred.child.java.opts` option in `conf/mapred-site.xml` to something higher than 2048MB,
but I'm concerned that might not be enough.

I'm launching my cluster using spark with the `--hadoop-major-version=yarn` option, so all MapReduce jobs are run through Yarn if I understand correctly, including jobs created by HDFS.

My question is: what other settings, if any, do I need to modify (and how do I determine their amounts, given that I want to use say 4GB for the mapreduce.child.java.opts setting) to increase the memory available to HDFS's MapReduce jobs?

Comment: Alex, you are confused between hdfs and yarn/mapreduce. Error is in namenode log, so you need to fix memory parameters in hadoop-env.sh and hdfs-site.xml (not yarn-site.xml and mapred-site.xml). Please rephrase your question to avoid the confusion.

Comment: adding to Durga's point , you could also check the clusters heap configured from the resource manager/jobtracker url

Comment: Sorry, traveled out of state after posting this and just got back online access. Durga, I understand your comments and find them helpful, but don't understand/agree with "correct way to increase hdfs java heap memory" being a confusing title, since i see the error in the namenode for hdfs --- but could you recommend a title that you feel is clearer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hadoop daemons control their JVM arguments, including heap size settings, through the use of environment variables that have names suffixed with `_OPTS`.  These environment variables are defined in various *-env.sh files in the configuration directory.

Using the NameNode as an example, you can set a line like this in your hadoop-env.sh file.

```
export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-Xms4G -Xmx4G $HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS"
```

This sets a minimum/maximum heap size of 4 GB for the NameNode and also preserves any other arguments that were placed into `HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS` earlier in the script.